# How to calculate gradient of partial log-likelihood function in Cox proportional hazards model?

Tags: r, cox-model, gradient-descent, likelihood

**Is there any existing function in R or package that calculates gradient of partial log-likelihood function in Cox proportional hazards model?**

I've tried myslef on this question ([How to compute gradient of partial log-likelihood function in Cox proportional hazards model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187395/how-to-compute-gradient-of-partial-log-likelihood-function-in-cox-proportional-h)) but it's probably too long to read so this is a summary of that question

Comment: If you're having trouble writing a function to calculate the first derivatives and you've written the likelihood function correctly, a good place to start is with a function that calculates the derivatives numerically. You can then use this to help debug the analytic calculations. I don't think I've ever successfully coded a derivative function without doing this.

Comment: I am not sure whether I have caluclated likelihood correctly. I am taking lok-lik values from `survival::coxph` and then there is C implementation for that I don't understand. example `coxph(Surv(t, c) ~ x, init = c(0), control=list('iter.max'=0))$loglik[2]`