# How does the lifelines package calculate the CoxPHFitter log-likelihood?

Tags: survival, likelihood, cox-model, lifelines

I'm looking for the equation that how the lifelines package calculates the log-likelihood of CoxPHFitter.

I read the lifelines documentation but cannot find where is it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute partial log-likelihood function in Cox proportional hazards model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187281/how-to-compute-partial-log-likelihood-function-in-cox-proportional-hazards-model) The linked question provides a formula. Anything very specific to a particular software package is off-topic on this site. If `lifelines` is open source, then the code is available for perusal.

Comment: @EdM Thanks for your help, I'm sorry about my off-topic question. I would take a perusal. Whatever, thanks!